# How can I get my system to email me when a critical issue is encountered, based on command output?

Tags: rsyslog

I would like my Linux system to have a script/syslog server such that it first telnets or logs in remotely to my other system, and then executes one command (e.g. netstat -an) and if the system found their anything with "syn_sent" it should generate an immediate email or sms.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Not really a specific question, you ask a lot of different things in one question. Consider doing a bit more research and asking  questions on specific issues.

Comment: I already told you that I am new to Linux so I don't have any idea that how many question I've asked. Furthermore I did research and then came to know about this site. If you don't help me then its better not to discourage someone.

Comment: Not meant to discourage but your question is just quite big making it hard to answer because there are many variables.
I'll answer the question by suggesting ways how to handle this without going into detail. The details you can then lookup on the internet and if not clear ask in a more specific question.

Comment: Is using syslog really a requirement?   You could use a logwatcher of some sort.   Or without syslog you could execute something from cron either remotely or locally to watch for the condition you want (and to email if it finds it).

Answer (score 1):

UNIX already supports (the pretty standard) syslog logging, which enables logging of kernel and application messages and even forwarding messages to other network hosts.

You could use a cronjob to periodicaly execute something like:

```
netstat -nntulpa | grep SYN_SENT | logger
```

This will write netstat output to the local logfiles.

To receive the logs on a central "loghost", all you need is one line in the syslog config. Depending on your syslog daemon of choice, this looks like:

```
*.* @192.168.5.1
```

On the receiving end, you can do all sorts of fancy stuff (even sending emails), provided you chose a fully-featured syslog implementation, such as syslog-ng or rsyslog.

Your question is too broad, you could also use a monitoring solution like Icinga and a custom plugin that executes the very same command (minus the logger part). Syslog is easier to setup and supported out of the box by most applications. I hope my answered helps you on the syslog side of your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I presume the purpose is to get an email or sms when a certain activity takes place on the other system you can do the polling like you suggest or make the other system send out a log message when this event takes place. Polling is the easiest option but slow and only useful for catching long events (unless latched at the other side).
Normally SYN_SENT happens a lot but is a fast process, polling on this without additional filtering would give kind of random behavior.

It would help to break down this question in multiple parts, it are many items in a single question.

To poll, this can be done by running a script via a cronjob which makes a connection and executes the command to see if the event takes place. Now this script can send out an email. If necessary the script can make its own log or can send a log message to syslog.

Possible questions or googles:

```
how to execute a script via a cronjob
how to setup the remote connection from script (security?)
how to detect your event
how to send out an email from script
how to do additional logging.
```

To respond directly on fast events you better configure the other system to send out a log message and make the activity logged.

Some firewall software will be able to do the logging on syn_sent, maybe even sent the log to a syslog server or you need a separate program for this. On the server side you then receive a message in you syslog-daemon which can be configured to execute a script which can send an email if necessary.

Possible questions other machine (only for askubuntu when it is an Ubuntu machine):

```
which firewall software
how to configure the firewall to log the event
which program to send to remote syslog
```

Possible questions on server:

```
how to configure syslog-daemon to run a script on incoming events
how to send out an email from script
```